# WCF in standalone application not use my custom binding

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I create console application with soap service and implement custom binding to modify incoming and outgoing messages.

I create service

```
public SoapService()
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SoapUri"]);
    host = new ServiceHost(this, uri);

    HttpTransportBindingElement transport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
    transport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024;

    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    smb.HttpGetUrl = uri;

    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISoapService), new CustomBinding(new GzipBinding(), transport), "");
    host.Open();
}
```

my custom binding is GzipBinding.

On client side I also want to use this binding. Code of creation client object:

```
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(new GzipBinding(), new HttpTransportBindingElement());
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RemoteSoapServer"]);

var soapClient = new ServiceReference.SoapServiceClient(binding, address))

soapClient.Upload(new file());
```

Problem is that then i create soap service overriden methods of GzipBinding are called as should, but on client side methods not called, and as I think my binding not used so finally I get exception about MessageVesrison mismatch. More - my client not trying connect to remote host it throw error then trying call method Upload. Any help pls.